# SQL Server 2017 on Linux. Job with a Powershell Step

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ubuntu

I have a SQL Server 2017 Standard on Ubuntu 20.04 and I would like to automate the backup process using a SQL Server Agent Job. This job will create the backup file and then will upload it to AWS S3.
To copy the .bak file to AWS S3 I would like to use AWS Tools for PowerShell (which I have installed on the EC2 instance) however I don't see the "PowerShell" task type in the SQL Server Job. This has always existed in SQL Server on Windows.

[image]

Is there something I can do to add a PowerShell step type to SQL Server on Linux?

Comment: @Larnu for now I created a Cron job for copying the back up file to D3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell execution is not supported on SQL Agent on SQL Server on Linux 2017; as noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2017?view=sql-server-ver15#Unsupported). This is true for 2019 as well.